# In a fixed width <select multiple> html box, is there a way to see text options that are to long?

Tags: html, css, select

I have the following code:

```
<div id='div2' style='height: 430px; width: 350px; overflow:auto;'>
<select multiple id="id" size="28" style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; width: 100%">
```

I cannot (due to requirements) increase the width of this box, its fixed at 350px.  However some of the text strings in the box are larger then 350px; right now they are just being truncated but I was wondering if there was a way to either make these options wrap onto a second line, or add a horizontal scrollbar to the box in order to see the full options.  I'm developing for IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 2):

you can use css 
word-wrap: break-word;

[click here](http://snipplr.com/view/10979/css-cross-browser-word-wrap/) for cross browser functionality

if it's the text inside the select list you want wrapped it's not possible as far as i know

what you could do is use a custom made selectbox for example the [jQuery Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) Where you can customize the look fully

Comment: Adding that tag to either the div style or the box style (or both) unfortunetly does not seem to work

Comment: press the link i've provided that will make sure it works in all browsers

Comment: if it's the content inside the select you want wrapped it's not possible as far as i know

Comment: ah-ha, yes I apologize if I was not clear, I want the content inside of the select to be wrapped

Comment: you're welcome make sure to try the selectmenu plugin it's very handy and works in pretty much every browser there is